# Google app engine key value error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am writing a google app engine app and I have this key value error upon requests coming in

from the backtrace I just access and cause the key error

```
self.request.headers
```

entire code snippet is here, I just forward the headers unmodified

```
     response = fetch( "%s%s?%s" % (
                                        self.getApiServer() ,
                                        self.request.path.replace("/twitter/", ""),
                                        self.request.query_string
                                    ),
                        self.request.body,
                        method,
                        self.request.headers,
                    )
```

and get method handling the request calling proxy()

```
# handle http get   
def get(self, *args):
    parameters = self.convertParameters(self.request.query_string)
    # self.prepareHeader("GET", parameters)
    self.request.query_string = "&".join("%s=%s" % (quote(key) , quote(value)) for key, value in parameters.items())
    self.proxy(GET, *args)
def convertParameters(self, source):
    parameters = {}
    for pairs in source.split("&"):
        item = pairs.split("=")
        if len(item) == 2:
            parameters[item[0]] = unquote(item[1])
    return parameters
```

the error back trace:

```
'CONTENT_TYPE'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 513, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/waytosing/1.342850593213842824/com/blogspot/zizon/twitter/RestApiProxy.py", line 67, in post
    self.proxy(POST, *args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/waytosing/1.342850593213842824/com/blogspot/zizon/twitter/RestApiProxy.py", line 47, in proxy
    self.request.headers,
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 240, in fetch
    allow_truncated, follow_redirects)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 280, in make_fetch_call
    for key, value in headers.iteritems():
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/UserDict.py", line 106, in iteritems
    yield (k, self[k])
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/webob/datastruct.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    return self.environ[self._trans_name(item)]
KeyError: 'CONTENT_TYPE'
```

Any idea why it happens or is this a known bug?

Comment: Where is this code? We need to see the complete handler class it's in.

Comment: is this enough for the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks weird. The [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-wsgiref.headers.html) mention that response "Headers objects do not raise an error when you try to get or delete a key that isn't in the wrapped header list. Getting a nonexistent header just returns None". It's not clear from the [request documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_headers) if request.headers are also objects of this class, but even they were regular dictionaries, `iteritems` seems to be misbehaving. So this might be a bug.

It might be worth inspecting self.request.headers, before calling `fetch`, and see 1) its actual type, 2) its keys, and 3) if trying to get self.request.headers['CONTENT_TYPE'] raises an error then.

But, if you simply want to solve your problem and move forward, you can try to bypass it like:

```
if 'CONTENT_TYPE' not in self.request.headers:
    self.request.headers['CONTENT_TYPE'] = None
```

(I'm suggesting setting it to None, because that's what a response Header object should return on non-existing keys)

Comment: No, it's not working, if you try anything that will iterate through the headers, it will raise error where it used to.

Comment: Does sound like a bug. Just to make sure: you are using App Engine's latest version, right? Also, try setting the content_type regardless. That is, don't check, just do `self.request.headers['CONTENT_TYPE'] = None`

Comment: overbooming: did setting the CONTENT_TYPE without checking work? Please let me know, and I'll edit the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my observation about this problem:
When the content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and POST data is empty (e.g. jquery.ajax GET, twitter's favorite and retweet API...), the content-type is dropped by Google appengine. 
You can add:

```
self.request.headers.update({'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

before urlfetch.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: indeed, looking at the error more carefully, it doesn't seem to be related to convertParameters, as the OP points out in the comments. I'm retiring this answer.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "just forward the headers unmodified", but have you taken a look at `self.request.query_string` before and after you call `convertParameters`? More to the point, you're leaving out any (valid) GET parameters of the form "key=" (that is, keys with empty values).

Maybe your original query_string had a value like "CONTENT_TYPE=", and your convertParameters is stripping it out.

Comment: convertParameters() in my idea is not relevant to the problem, according to the backtrace I provided, the error is happening when I am doing iterating over self.request.headers

Answer (score 0):

Known issue http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3427 and potential workarounds here http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2040

Comment: It's known because the OP (him|her)self opened it :). Also, the workaround links to an issue which should be fixed on 1.3.2. Current version is 1.3.5 (I suppose/hope the OP is using the latest app engine version)

Comment: It really does look like it could be caused by the issue your second link points to. I hope the OP is using the latest SDK.